# Why am I getting a KeyError AFTER it finds and prints the URL just fine?

Tags: python-3.x, google-knowledge-graph

For some reason, I am getting the URL that I was looking for, but afterwards, I still get a KeyError, and I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

input:

```
"""Example of Python client calling Knowledge Graph Search API."""
import json
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

api_key = 'my api key'
query = 'voi'
service_url = 'https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search'
params = {
    'query': query,
    'limit': 10,
    'indent': True,
    'key': api_key,
}
url = service_url + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
response = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
for element in response['itemListElement']:
    print(element['result']['detailedDescription']['url'])
```

output:

```
C:\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/NikkiL/PycharmProjects/experimenting/knowledgegraph.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voi
  File "C:/Users/NikkiL/PycharmProjects/experimenting/knowledgegraph.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(element['result']['detailedDescription']['url'])
KeyError: 'detailedDescription'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As you can see from the output, where it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voi
```

That is the URL that I was looking for, but why does it find it with no problem and then throw an error?

This is the structure of the data from print(element):

```
{'@type': 'EntitySearchResult', 'result': {'@id': 'kg:/m/08wy0_', 'name': `'Voi', '@type': ['Thing', 'Place', 'City'], 'description': 'Town in Kenya', 'image': {'contentUrl': 'http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfSu6k0uKR5Gr4VoeGH6zxZ2qsXmfbN7O-HGnd-Jy0YuSxxb6n', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voi'}, 'detailedDescription': {'articleBody': 'Voi is the largest town in Taita-Taveta County in southern Kenya, in the former Coast Province. It lies at the western edge of the Taru Desert, south and west of the Tsavo East National Park. The Sagala Hills are to the south. Voi is also a municipality.', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voi', 'license': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License'}}, 'resultScore': 38.771496}`
```

Comment: I just made an edit to show the structure. thanks!

Comment: My guess is that there are some results inside your `itemListElement` that do _not_ contain the `detailedDescription` element. Just check for that explicitly (`if 'detailedDescription' in element['result']`) and print out the `element` when it is not the case so you can debug further.

Comment: I'm guessing that not every item in the list you are iterating over has a `detailedDescription` ?

Comment: I assume that Voi would use the [Place](https://schema.org/Place) schema, rather than the Person?

Comment: at the bottom i showed the results of print(element)

Comment: @poke that worked for me, thank you!